# Python import with modification

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, repo

I always structure my repos in the following way.

```
repo/main.py
repo/scripts/script.py
…
```

In main.py, I import script.py in the following manner:

```
from scripts import script as sc
```

This always works unless I decide to make changes to script.py. After making changes, if I run main.py from shell, it still imports code from the older script.py without the current changes. Until now, what I would then is just create another branch. However, this leads to a lot of branches in the development process. Is there any way to avoid this? How else should I be importing from the scripts directory to avoid this?

Help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
From the answers, I can see that I have caused some confusion. What I mean when I say that *I run main.py from shell*, I mean executing it with `python main.py` from the terminal. One can think of *main.py* as a script that does some math and outputs the answer. In doing those math, it imports *script.py* from *scripts* that has additional functions that it (*main.py*) uses. After running *main.py* N times, if I choose to update *script.py*, and then I execute *main.py* again (in the terminal), it imports the old *script.py* again and does the math with the older code. The answer does not reflect the changes I just made to *script.py*. Until now, what I have done, when I have had to go through something like this is just create another new branch and literally copy-paste the old files and the newer *script.py* in the new branch and execute *main.py* in the shell. It does import the newer *script.py* then. One more thing I have noticed is that if I just create a new file as say *script2.py* and then import it in *main.py* as

```
from scripts import script2 as sc
```

it imports *script2.py* just as it should - it reflects all the changes made to *script.py*.

There’s no second *import* statement in *main.py*.

Comment: "Until now, what I would then is just create another branch." - creating a new branch shouldn't change anything.

Comment: "After making changes, if I run main.py from shell" - how are you running it? The behavior you're describing isn't what you'd get if you just ran `python main.py` in a terminal. It sounds more like you're reexecuting the contents of `main.py` in an ongoing Python session. Are you running it in an IDE? Give details.

Comment: @user2357112 I’m running it in terminal with `python main.py`. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface this question sounds like we're repeatedly running
`$ python main.py`,
which quickly executes and exits.

But from the symptom, it must be the case that
we have a long-lived REPL prompt repeatedly executing the main.py code.

---

The module you're looking for is
[importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).

Do this:

```
from importlib import reload

from scripts import script as sc

# [do stuff, then edit script.py]

reload(sc)

# [do more stuff, and see the effect of the edit]
```

---

What is going on here?

Well, if you repeatedly execute

```
import scripts.script
import scripts.script
```

it turns out that the 2nd and subsequent import does nothing.
It consults `sys.modules`, finds the module has *already*
been loaded, and reports "cache hit!" instead of doing
the hard work of pulling in that text file.

The purpose of the `reload()` function is to
do a cache invalidate and repeat the import, so it actually
pulls in python text from the (presumably edited) source file.

---

Suppose you have a short-lived `$ python main.py` process
that runs repeatedly, sometimes after a script.py edit.
So the in-memory `sys.module` cache is not relevant,
having been discarded each time the process exits.
There *is* another level of caching at work here.

Typically the cPython interpreter will read `script.py`,
parse, produce bytecode from the parse tree, and write
the bytecode to `script.pyc`. More than one output cache
directory is possible, depending on system details.

Upon being asked to read `script.py`, the interpreter
can look to see if the corresponding `.pyc` bytecode file
is available and fresh, and then declare "cache hit!",
in which case the `.py` source file is not even read.
Normally this works great, because source file updates
are infrequent (human editing speed), and the freshness
comparison of file timestamps is effective. If there's
something wrong with those timestamps the whole mechanism
won't work properly, and we might fail to notice the
source was recently edited. Perhaps you suffer from this.

First, identify the relevant `.pyc` bytecode file.

Then, run main, make an edit, **delete** the `.pyc` file,
re-run main, and notice that the edit took effect.

---

[Let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
how it goes.